# Native, hybrid, and web app definitions

Tags: ios

Can anyone help me in understanding what the difference is between hybrid, native and web applications for iOS?

Answer (score 5):

Summarizing:

- **Native**: Its a proper iPhone App, built with Objective-C and the iPhone SDK. You will download it by the App Store and install in your phone.
- **Web App** It's just a web page, prepared to be opened with your iPhone. You access it via Internet, and you dont need to install anything in your phone. They are built with for example in HTML5
- **Hybrid** As you can imagine, its a mix of both, its an App built as a Native App, but implements some functionality via web

You can find a nice presentation about this here:

http://www.slideshare.net/grigs/native-vs-mobile-web-vs-hybrid-apps-for-mobile-development

Answer (score 0):

An application built using the ios sdk provided by Apple is called a native application. It must be built with Apple provided frameworks and classes. Web apps are built using HTML5, Javascript, CSS and are loaded in Safari. You can find web apps on http://www.apple.com/webapps/. And about Hybrid apps, they are also written in HTML5, JavaScript, CSS and compiled using tools such as phoneGap which compile to different platforms like android, blackberry, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**For iOS**,

**Native:-** use language is Objective C or swift.tool is XCode and hardware is Mac.Have advanced UI interactions.Faster performance.You can download and install app using App-store. Full(100%) capabilities.This apps can access to the phone's various devices eg:- camera,address book.Sometimes can use these apps without internet.

**Web:-**  This is the opposite of native app.Used web technologies.such as HTML 5,css,JavaScript. No need install and upgrade anythings.Can access through browser.Therefore always need internet connection.But have run anywhere approach.Can't access to the phone's various devices.

**Hybrid:-** This combined best components of native and web.Build using HTML 5,css,JavaScript and wrapped by a thin native container. App-store distribution.Also can access to the phone's various devices.